# El carousel de bootstrap no aparece y el jumpbotron que agregue no esta como en el ejemplo USO PYTHON

Tags: html, python, bootstrap

soy principiante y estoy intentando crear una página web con python, css y html (creo q para algunos es obvio). El motivo es que cuando agrego el carousel no aparece como debería y quisiera solucionarlo. Tambien, el jumpbotron que agrege al inicio no aparece como en el ejemplo. Estoy usando python para el index, es decir index.py. El carousel esta arriba de la pagina que hice. agradeceria cualquire apoyo. Lo hice con un tutorial de ``fazt. ADJUNTO EL CODIGO FUENTE.

```
LAYOUT.HTML

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Mi profesor</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

<body>

    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" >
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</head>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Python web app</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                   </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container p-4">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
   </body>

</html>

HOME.HTML
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to
            featured content or information.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

[image: Este es el ejemplo del jumbotron que elegi]

[image: Esta es la pagina que estoy creando, el carousel se encuentra arriba del navbar o ahi deberia estar..]

Comment: No veo que añadas los scripts de bootstrap por ninguna parte...

Comment: Estas implementando una plantilla muy mal, ¿Porque sigue habiendo HTML despues de cerrar la etiqueta?

Comment: Disculpen, lo copiado de bootstrap empieza aqi

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

¿eso es el script cierto? :( disculpen, aun soy nuevo

Oh verdad, a partir de "HOME,HTML" es otro archivo, solo que no pude separarlos en 2 cuadrados distintos durante la publicación.

Comment: Lo que si me salio bien y sin errores fue el "navbar", efue lo unico que me salio igual al ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

acá te dejo un carrusel con JS de boostrap, te recomiendo leerlo y entenderlo, cambiales las imágenes que las robe de su misma pagina, eso funciona pero si le cambias por algunas que tengas de forma local ira mas fluido. Arregla la forma de escribir tu código, donde cierran y abren las etiquetas tambien

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1772ed645d6%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1772ed645d6%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22276.9921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1772ed645d6%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1772ed645d6%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22276.9921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1772ed645d6%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1772ed645d6%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22276.9921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

No se si necesitas algo mas?
Si queres ver como el JS del carrusel es [este](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js)

Comment: Gracias, lo acabo de hacer pero sigue igual :(

Comment: te aconsejo que lo hagas por html separedos, luego cuando te funciona lo copias y pegas en el siguiente, la verdad es media rara tu forma de incluir un html luego de cerrar otro, eso esta mal, lo que si puede hacer es incluirlo antes de cerrar pero de igual modo lo que incluyas no tiene que tener las etiquetas de <html> ni <body> o sea es como si el codigo continuara

Comment: Hay algo llamado JavaScript, un lenguaje de programacion y en html se puede usar en una etiqueta llamada <script></script> dentro del script programas el comportamiento de carrucel, si lees la documentación oficial [enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#via-javascript) ahi te redirigira la parte exacta donde habla de javaScript

Comment: Aca un ejemplo de lo que tendria que ir en el   ` <script> $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
}) <script> ` recuerda que cuando se trata de "animaciones" en palabras simple se trabajan por lo general en JS (JavaScript) o en otros casos css

Comment: oh entiendo gracias, sino que usaba python con html, use 2 archivos de html ya que 1 de ellos lo usaba como plantilla, no se si este bien pero si, mejor hare en uno que salga bien y ahi recien pegar, apenas voy aprendiendo muchas gracias!. Solo me queda una duda es preferible usar javascript o python para crear una pagina. Si, soy muy nuevo..